# Determinate the coordonnates of the beginning and the end of a water pipe section

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pipe, coordinates, shapefile

Good Evening,

I am working on a new project and cleaning up the water network data of the city I work with. I am using pandas and gdf.

The network is a shapefile with a correct crs. I don't know if it possible but I'd like to create a shapefile with points representing the end and the beginning of each pipe section. The final objective is to have the coordinates (x,y) of each point.

Do you have any idea ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add some reproducible example

Comment: Considering I have a dataset of 7000 lines, I would like to get the endingpoint and startpoint of each line. `